# how to make mongoDB query with relation between 3 collections

Tags: php, mongodb, relational-database

I have these 3 mongoDB collections :

client_results

```
[
 'resultId':1,
 'clientId':'client00',
],
[
 'resultId':2,
 'clientId':'client00',
],
```

results

```
[
'id':1,
'siteID':5
],
[
'id':2,
'siteID':6
]
```

sites

```
[
'id':5,
'language':'ar'
],
[
'id':6,
'language':'en'
]
```

how I can get client_results  where results.site.language = 'en' ? 
in MYSQL query will like this :

```
select cr.id, cr.clientId from client_results cr
left join results r
  on r.id = cr.resultId 
left join site s
  on s.id = r.siteID
where s.language = 'en';
```

but in mongoDB how I can make this query ?

thanks

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far to the post.

Comment: MongoDB version? If 3.2, please try something with [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and tell us where your are stuck?

Comment: thanks Styvane.. I stuck in "how I can put condition with $lookup", I need the results that site.language equal 'en'.

Comment: `$lookup` does not allow you to add conditions. Seems that you'll need a better database, a relational one. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mongodb it is little hectic to do joins,as mongodb was not meant to do joins,the main idea behind mongodb was to put all you need in one document,but there are some limitation,we cant put whole other document in another,anyways here is your answer,$look is like left outer join,But problem in this solution is there i have unwind the first table to join another,in this case if there is no first join there would be no second join as well,
You can use a $project stage and put a _id variable in it,play with it you will get the desired result

```
db.client_results.aggregate([
                            {"$lookup" : 
                             {
                              from : results,
                              localField : resultId,
                              foreignField: id,
                              as : "resultTable"
                            }
                          },
                      {"$unwind" : "$resultTable"},
                      {"$lookup" : 
                         {
                          from : sites,
                          localField : "resultTable.siteID",
                          foreignField: id,
                          as : "siteTable"
                         }
                       },
                      {"$unwind" : "$siteTable"},
                      {$match : {"siteTable.language" : "en"}} // <-- only en language
                        ])
```

Comment: Thanks very much #Parshuram ,this good but there is not condition, is there way to put condition like "site.language = en", I mean I need only results that sites languages are 'en'... thanks again